# How to add post_install script in my podspec file?

Tags: ios, swift, podspec, podfile

How can I add `post_install` script in `podspec` file of my custom cocoapod and execute code below?

```
post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
  end
end
```

I have an issue where I can not get a successful build when running `pod spec lint` because of dependencies of my cocoapod. When I remove those dependencies and run `pod spec lint` I get a successful build.

On images below is shown when script fails:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcivm.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mWyt.png)

This is the reason why I wan't to execute `post_install` in `podspec` file. I'm not sure will this resolve the issue or should I look for some other solutions.

I've tried adding `post_install` like this but I get an error:

```
s.post_install do |installer|
    # your script here
end
```

but I get an error:

```
[!] Invalid `MyLib.podspec` file: undefined method `post_install' for #<Pod::Specification name="MyLib">
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for tihs? I am struggling too.

Comment: I guess you are missing pod install, since your code is setting iOS 14 but you are still getting errors about the target being set to 8.